# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS error when checking for software updates

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-sources

Since 20th june 2013 I have tried running the software updater in ubuntu 12.04 LTS however it runs but returns this error

```
W:Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  406  Not Acceptable
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It seems to tell me my internet is not connected but it is at the time of the update.

Could anyone let me know what the problem is and where there might be a fix for it?

Comment: I am only getting this issue on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS **server**. *Is this desktop or server?*

Comment: *Just rechecked on netbook (32-bit, 12.04) and desktop (64-bit, 12.04), with no issues.*

Comment: What (country) mirror are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating and upgrading from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it works, then the server was temporarily down. If not, you can enter `software souces' in dash, choose 'Software & Updates', and select a different server.

[image]